# Searching through both .text() and data- attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search box:

```
<input id="box" type="text" />
```

where I search through a list:

```
<ons-list class="ng-scope list ons-list-inner">

  <ons-list-item data-alt-name="Granny Smith" class="list__item">Apple</ons-list-item>

  <ons-list-item data-alt-name="Valencia" class="list__item">Orange</ons-list-item>

  <ons-list-item data-alt-name="Hokkaido" class="list__item">Melon</ons-list-item>

</ons-list>
```

with:

```
$('#box').keyup(function() {
                  var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                  if (valThis == "") {
                    $('.list > .list__item').show();
                  } else {
                    $('.list > .list__item').each(function() {
                      var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                      if (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) {
                        $(this).show()
                      } else {
                        $(this).hide();
                      }
                    });
                  };
                });
```

The problem is, it's only searching `.text()` but I want it to search also `data-alt-name` so that it shows if it matches EITHER of them. I already tried with `$(this).attr("data-alt-name")` but for some reason it's not working.

Any help or hint is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `text = ($(this).text() + ' ' + $(this).data('altName')).toLowerCase()` will do?

Comment: DISCLAIMER: It can hit results for strings like `le gra` which is a substring of `Apple Granny Smith`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working snippet using `$(this).data("alt-name")`

```js
$('#box').keyup(function() {
  var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  if (valThis == "") {
    $('.list > .list__item').show();
  } else {
    $('.list > .list__item').each(function() {
      var text = ($(this).text() + $(this).data("alt-name")).toLowerCase();
      if (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) {
        $(this).show()
      } else {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    });
  };
});
```

```css
.list__item {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="box" type="text" />

<ons-list class="ng-scope list ons-list-inner">

  <ons-list-item data-alt-name="Granny Smith" class="list__item">Apple</ons-list-item>

  <ons-list-item data-alt-name="Valencia" class="list__item">Orange</ons-list-item>

  <ons-list-item data-alt-name="Hokkaido" class="list__item">Melon</ons-list-item>

</ons-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of show/hide you can use:

> [.toggle( display )](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display): where display can be true to show the element or false to hide it.

You can change:

```
var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
if (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) {
   $(this).show()
} else {
   $(this).hide();
}
```

With:

```
var text = ($(this).text().toLowerCase() + 
          $(this).data('altName')).toLocaleLowerCase();
$(this).toggle(text.indexOf(valThis) != -1);
```

```js
$('#box').on('input', function(e) {
  var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  if (valThis == "") {
      $('.list > .list__item').show();
  } else {
      $('.list > .list__item').each(function() {
          var text = ($(this).text().toLowerCase() + $(this).data('altName')).toLocaleLowerCase();
          $(this).toggle(text.indexOf(valThis) != -1);
      });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input id="box" type="text" />
<ons-list class="ng-scope list ons-list-inner">

    <ons-list-item data-alt-name="Granny Smith" class="list__item">Apple</ons-list-item>

    <ons-list-item data-alt-name="Valencia" class="list__item">Orange</ons-list-item>

    <ons-list-item data-alt-name="Hokkaido" class="list__item">Melon</ons-list-item>

</ons-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the `data()` method:

```
$(this).data("alt-name")
```

This works perfectly with data attributes and will return the secondary value to perform a search on.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try with

```
this.attributes["data-alt-name"].value
```

This will also improve performance

Answer (score 0):

One other simple solution in your case would be to search the outer HTML

```
var text = $(this)[0].outerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

Selecting by text is unpleasant. I'd take a step back and before you bind your `keyup` handler, create a new `data-` attribute that has the text you want.

```
var els = $(".list > .list__item").text(function(i, txt) {
  this.setAttribute("data-text", txt.trim().toLowerCase());
  this.setAttribute("data-alt-name", this.dataset.altName.toLowerCase());
  return txt;
});
```

Then you can use the selector engine cleanly.

```
$('#box').keyup(function() {
  var valThis = this.value.trim().toLowerCase();

  if (valThis == "") {
    els.show();
  } else {
    els.hide()
      .filter(`[data-text*='${valThis}'], [data-alt-name*='${valThis}']`)
      .show();
  };
});
```

---

Full demo:

```js
var els = $(".list > .list__item").text(function(i, txt) {
  this.setAttribute("data-text", txt.trim().toLowerCase());
  this.setAttribute("data-alt-name", this.dataset.altName.toLowerCase());
  return txt;
});

$('#box').keyup(function() {
  var valThis = this.value.trim().toLowerCase();

  if (valThis == "") {
    els.show();
  } else {
    els.hide()
      .filter(`[data-text*='${valThis}'], [data-alt-name*='${valThis}']`)
      .show();
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="box" type="text" />

<ons-list class="ng-scope list ons-list-inner">
  <ons-list-item data-alt-name="Granny Smith" class="list__item">Apple</ons-list-item>
  <ons-list-item data-alt-name="Valencia" class="list__item">Orange</ons-list-item>
  <ons-list-item data-alt-name="Hokkaido" class="list__item">Melon</ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
```